# Are there any Worpdress plugins to change the theme editor?

Tags: plugin-recommendation, theme-development, editor

I've been browsing around a bit, but haven't been able to find any plugins for changing the default theme editor. Currently it's a text area with no syntax highlighting. I'd like something that at least gives syntax highlighting. There are all sorts of plugins for the post editor, but I've yet to find one for the theme editor.

If all else fails, I'll make one myself, but I thought I would ask here before I did that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**@Jack Slingerland,**

There are a few plugins that do this but the only one I that has been updated recently is [Power Code Editor](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/power-code-editor/).  At a recent WordCamp Matt mentioned that a new built in theme editor with a trash bin and revisions is on the road map but I have not heard it mentioned in any of the dev meetings.