# syntax highlighting for theme-editor.php?

Tags: customization, syntax-highlighting

Is there any syntax highlighter for wordpress. This is not to post code snippets on posts but for the backend/theme editor of wordpress.

If not do you think it will be implemented in sometime future?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are there any Worpdress plugins to change the theme editor?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1474/are-there-any-worpdress-plugins-to-change-the-theme-editor)

Answer (score 1):

yes there is [WP Editarea plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-editarea/screenshots/) works on both plugin and theme editor.

and there is [Power Code Editor](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/power-code-editor/) plugin